# Do all the parts have to be linked?

Tags: modeling, mesh, game-engine

The title may confuse some, but I ask, Do all the little parts of the mesh have to be linked? as in, my model consists of many shapes that would be a bit tedious/hard to connect. like multiple un-linked cubes that simply clip into each other. They're all the same object, but they're not Linked.

I ask this because A lot of the tutorials I find just give enough information on the modeling process to interest potential customers.

I also see a lot of other people make (presumably) rigged characters while doing this.

I plan on putting this character into the Unreal engine, so... anything?

down below is a better example.
[image: here, like this.]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It really depends on how you want things to look in the end. It doesn't mean you will notice a difference if you were to connect them.
If you try to connect complex parts you also end up with a higher vertex count.

Inherently there is nothing wrong with having loose parts. Lots of weapons are made like that.

If you intend to control some parts trough code or animation, having them in separate objects works too.

I say play around with it and see what you're comfortable with. This is going to be a trial and error journey on your part anyways. Ultimately it comes down to technical choices and the workflow that works for your project.

Comment: Thank you, this helps out a lot. I was wondering because I had heard people say that certain unconnected meshes would "fall apart" in the game engine. I appreciate this, thanks again.

Comment: Falling apart is likely a result of having rigidbodies on them. The loose parts should transform with the parent tho. You have full control over this. Note that there is a difference between seperate objects and loose mesh parts, as in it's one mesh but some elements are not connected.